# Maximum Value of an array

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let's have a sequence a1, a2, ..., an. Define the strength of the sequence to be

```
|a1 - a2| + |a2 - a3| + ... + |an-1 - an| + |an - a1|.
```

I wants to make his sequence stronger, so I reorders this sequence into a new sequence b1, b2, ..., bn. What is the largest possible strength of the resulting sequence?
if ai can be negative also

Comment: My Idea [without proof]: Choose $b_1$ to be the maximum value, $b_2$ to be the minimum value, $b_3$ to be the second-biggest value, $b_4$ to be the second-smallest value etc.. Also, you can wlog assume $a_i$ to be nonnegative, since the sequence $c_i = a_i + c$ has the same strength as $a_i$ for every $c$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best possible way to do it is to sort the sequence in ascending order:
$$
c_1\geq c_2\geq c_3\geq ...\geq c_n
$$
And then take the following sequence as the strongest:
$$
c_n,c_2,c_{n-2},c_4,c_{n-4},...,c_{n-3},c_3, c_{n-1}, c_1
$$